# How to call a lambda function from above?

Tags: python

I am trying to use my interest multiplier function from above and use that in the compound interest rate function but cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
interest_multiplier = lambda r, n: (1 + (r/n))
print ("The interest multiplier is: ", interest_multiplier(.05,1))

compound_interest_rate = lambda interest_multiplier, n, t: interest_multiplier ** (n*t)
print ("The compund interest rate is: ", compound_interest_rate(interest_multiplier, n, 1))
```

Comment: Why do you think you are doing anything wrong? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Why are you even using `lambda` here? It doesn't make sense to use an anonymous function and then give it a name. Might as well just use the full `def`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interest_multiplier = lambda r, n: (1 + (r/n))
print ("The interest multiplier is: ", interest_multiplier(.05,1))
```

This is exactly correct. You call a lambda function just like any other function.

```
compound_interest_rate = lambda interest_multiplier, n, t: interest_multiplier ** (n*t)
print ("The compund interest rate is: ", compound_interest_rate(interest_multiplier, n, 1))
```

The problem here is that you are passing `interest_multiplier` to `compound_interest_rate` then using the `**` operator with it. You cannot raise a function to a power in Python. I believe that you want to use the `interest_multiplier` function inside the `compount_interest_rate` function:

```
compound_interest_rate = lambda r, n, t: interest_multiplier(r, n) ** (n*t)
```

Note that I modified `compount_interest_rate` to have an argument named `r`. I also call `interest_multiplier` with the correct arguments.